# Extracting PDF text into a text file using Python - Extraction error

Tags: python

I want to first extract all the text from 1 pdf file and store it into one text file.

Here is my code:

```
import PyPDF2
from pathlib import Path

with Path('C:/Users/Lui/Desktop/Test/file1.pdf').open(mode='rb') as pdf_file, open('Extracted/extractPDF.txt', 'w') as text_file:
    read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
    number_of_pages = read_pdf.getNumPages()
    print(number_of_pages)
    for page_number in range(number_of_pages):   # use xrange in Py2
        page = read_pdf.getPage(page_number)
        page_content = page.extractText()
        print(page_content)
        text_file.write(page_content)
```

The pdf looks like this:
[image]

[image]

However, the text file created looks different in comparison with missing words and spacing:
[image: Extracted Text]

What am I doing wrong? My goal is to then loop through 1,000 PDF's so I'm trying to get 1 example working first.

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong.  PDF files are designed to be printed, not read.  The text strings are not always stored in the order you see them on the page.  It has done a pretty good job here, but there are other PDF text extractors you can try.  None of them are perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [pdftotext](https://github.com/jalan/pdftotext)

```
import pdftotext

# Load your PDF
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        pdf = pdftotext.PDF(f)

    # If it's password-protected
    #with open("secure.pdf", "rb") as f:
    #    pdf = pdftotext.PDF(f, "secret")

    # How many pages?
    #print(len(pdf))

    # Iterate over all the pages
    #for page in pdf:
    #    print(page)

    data = "\n\n".join(pdf)
    # Read all the text into one string
    print(data)
```

This package works far better and should help you out.